# Baked normal map with empty patches where UVs are

Tags: baking, normal-map

I have been trying to bake a normal map of a keyboard. I have this base low poly mesh, and what I want to do is emulate the buttons of the keyboard with a normal map. But when I bake the high poly mesh into the low poly, my normal map turns out purple in the parts of the image where there are no UVs, and it looks completely empty in the parts where the UVs are located.

(Now, in the never ending research I've been doing today I discovered that maybe a normal map is not the correct way of achieving what i want, so I would like to know if that's the case if possible. However, I **think** the problem that I have is independent to that, and what I should be getting is a completely purple image. Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Thank you.

[image: Low poly mesh]

[image: Mesh with buttons]

[image]

Comment: I can't say for sure w/o seeing your UV's and without "backface culling" turned on, but I wonder about 2 things:

1) Did you "correctly" unwrap the UV's of your low poly mesh after it was in its final form? For me, that would involve marking seems along the top and bottom edges and marking a seem along at least one vertical edge, then hitting "Unwrap UV's".

2) Are all the normals facing outward (check by turning on "backface culling").

I don't know how experienced you are. Sometimes this process is frustrating. Sometimes we make simple oversights and sometimes Blender takes a dump.

Comment: ...also, your Ray Distance is set to `0.5`, which seems really big for a keyboard that is modeled to-scale. try taking that down to 0.01, 0.02, or 0.05. That might solve your problem

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/